# FETCH not associated field_name from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have tables like below,

**Table 1 :**

| ID | FIELD_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | field_1 |
| 2 | field_2 |
| 3 | field_3 |

**Table 2 :**

| ID | TAG_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tag_1 |
| 2 | tag_2 |
| 3 | tag_3 |
| 4 | tag_4 |

**Table 3 :**

| FIELD_ID | TAG_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

so table-3 shows :

field1(from table1) connected with all 3 tag id's of table-2

field2(from table1) connected with all  tag id=1 of table-2

and

field3(from table1) connected with all  tag id=2,3 of table-2

I like to write a **MYSQL Query to fetch**

**for a given tag_name, find all field name which are NOT associated with this**

Example :

input  = tag_1

output = field_3

Explanation : as field_3 not have any relation with tag_1 id

input  = tag_4

output = field_1, field_2, field_3

Explanation : as no field have any relation with tag_4 id

Comment: You have a simple 3 table solution for *many-to-many* relationship. Text book case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for fields where certain link table entries do not exist...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM table3
     WHERE field_id = table1.id
       AND   tag_id = (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE tag_name = 'tag_4')
  )
```

dbfiddle as borrowed from @nbk : [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8c400d9ffb9a6214285fcfaae83a0357)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `CROSS` join of `table1` to `table2` and a `LEFT` join yo `table3` where you return the unmatched rows:

```
SELECT t2.TAG_NAME, t1.FIELD_NAME
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.FIELD_ID = t1.ID AND t3.TAG_ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.TAG_NAME = ? AND t3.FIELD_ID IS NULL
```

If you want the results as comma separated list you can also group by `TAG_NAME` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT t2.TAG_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.FIELD_NAME) fields
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.FIELD_ID = t1.ID AND t3.TAG_ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.TAG_NAME = ? AND t3.FIELD_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY t2.TAG_NAME
```

Replace `?` with the tag that you search for.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6dc73ebf5003977a7a226de840766bc).